# Solving equation involving binomial function

Tags: binomial-coefficients, problem-solving, closed-form

Solve for $x$ in terms of $i$ and $j$:

$$
\binom{x}{i} = j
$$

where $x$ is Real; $i$ and $j$ are Integers: $x \geqslant i$, $i \geqslant1$, $j \geqslant 0$.

I came across this problem while trying to **unrank** [combinations](http://www2.denizyuret.com/bib/kreher/donald1999combinatorial/combinatorialA.pdf) $\binom{n}{k}$, pp. 51, Algorithm 2.12. I tried the following:

$$
Minimize \left | \binom{x}{i}-j \right | 
$$

$$
s.t. x\geqslant i
$$

A plot of $|\binom{x}{i}-j|$ for $i=20$ and $j=10$ is the following:

[image: Plot]

I ignore if there is a closed-form for the real solutions of $x$ in terms of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Are $x,i,j$ supposed to be integers ?

Comment: Where have you found this problem? Do you know, that there is a closed-form for it? Any addition information about the problem?

Comment: A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/948754/153012).

Comment: Thank you for your interest and further development on the topic

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle{x\choose i}$ is a polynomial of degree *i* in *x*. For $i<5$, we have the [linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#One_variable), [quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function#Roots), [cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots), and [quartic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) formulas for roots. Otherwise, the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Ruffini_theorem) informs us that no such general formula exists. $~$ Nevertheless, the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) or other [polynomial factorization methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials) might prove helpful. However, I am afraid that recourse to [numerical methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) is ultimately unavoidable.

Comment: $\binom{x}{i}$ is not just any polynomial of degree $i$ but it is a very specific kind of polynomial. I don't see how Abel-Ruffini is interesting here.

Comment: @JiK: There are no known closed forms for the inverses of the $\Gamma$ and beta functions.

Comment: @Lucian There is a closed form for $i=4$. As you said Abel–Ruffini theorem informs us that no general formula exist. But this problem is a special case.

Comment: @user153012: Yes. Very special. A [special function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), in fact. But being special and possessing an inverse expressible in terms of elementary functions are two completely different things. The best that I can think of is an approximation using Stirling.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer I generated some solutions using CAS.

For $i=1$: $x_1 = j.$

For $i=2$:

$$x_1 = 1/2+1/2\,\sqrt {1+8\,j},$$
$$x_2 = 1/2-1/2\,\sqrt {1+8\,j}.$$

For $i=3$:

$$x_1 = 1/3\,\sqrt [3]{81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}+{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{
81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}}}+1,$$

$$x_2 = -1/6\,\sqrt [3]{81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}-1/2\,{\frac {1}{
\sqrt [3]{81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}}}+1+1/2\,i\sqrt {3} \left( 
1/3\,\sqrt [3]{81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}-{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{
81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}}} \right),$$

$$x_3 = -1/6\,\sqrt [3]{81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}-1/2\,{\frac {1}{
\sqrt [3]{81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}}}+1-1/2\,i\sqrt {3} \left( 
1/3\,\sqrt [3]{81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}-{\frac {1}{\sqrt [3]{
81\,j+3\,\sqrt {729\,{j}^{2}-3}}}} \right).$$

For $i=4$:

$$x_1 = 3/2+1/2\,\sqrt {5+4\,\sqrt {1+24\,j}},$$

$$x_2 = 3/2-1/2\,\sqrt {5+4\,\sqrt {1+24\,j}},$$

$$x_3 = 3/2+1/2\,\sqrt {5-4\,\sqrt {1+24\,j}},$$

$$x_4 = 3/2-1/2\,\sqrt {5-4\,\sqrt {1+24\,j}}.$$

For $i=5$ I didn't find closed-form.

And the solutions for $i=6$ are [here](http://mathb.in/20624?key=024753f6d84cce526e5eaaa197658563b17faf72).

I'm also very interested in a general solution.

Comment: The case $i=8$ also has an expression in radicals.

Comment: @Lucian I know, but because of the solution of $x^4+14x^3+63x^2+90x-2520j=0$ for $x$ is a [very large](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28x%5E4%2B14*x%5E3%2B63*x%5E2-2520*j%2B90*x%2Cx%29) expression, and we need this roots in case of $i=8$, so I didn't posted it. At least I didn't find a appropriate simplification.