# Fitting a closed curve on the roots of ${x \choose k}-c$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, binomial-coefficients, roots, curves

Let
$${n \choose k} = \frac1{(n+1) \operatorname{B}(n-k+1, k+1)}.$$
be the generalized binomial coefficient, and here $\operatorname{B}$ is the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Let $f_{k,c}(x)$ be the following function

$$f_{k,c}(x) = {x \choose k}-c,$$

where $k$ and $c$ are nonzero scalars.

Are there a special general closed curve, what we can fit on the roots of $f_{k,c}$?

The roots on the complex plane for [$(k,c)=(6,1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28binomial%28x%2C6%29%3D1%2Cx%29), [$(k,c)=(9,1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28binomial%28x%2C9%29%3D1%2Cx%29), [$(k,c)=(15,1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28binomial%28x%2C15%29%3D1%2Cx%29) are the followings.

[image]

The results are similar for other $(k,c)$ pairs. First I thought that it is an ellipse, but actually after fitting ellipses on arbirtrary five roots of higher order $f_{k,c}$ functions it turned out that it is not. The motivation of the problem was [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/946783/153012).

Comment: I suspect the exact curve isn't something that appears elsewhere, but it might have a more identifiable limit curve as various parameters approach limits (perhaps after some scaling).

Comment: I think the nice curve that we are seeing is $|\binom{x}{k}|=|c|$.

Comment: I recommend the scaling $x = kz + (k-1)/2$ for now; this gives symmetry in the roots and seems to properly scale their moduli.

Comment: Continuing the conversation with @AntonioVargas from meta, I think the problem with my answer isn't that it's too obvious, but that it might not actually be the best choice.  There are of course infinitely many algebraic curves passing through the $f_{k,c}$, and perhaps there is a simpler one than what I wrote down.  I don't know how to characterize that precisely.  However, looking at what happens to my curve for small values of $|c|$ (say, for $|c|$ just big enough that there are at most 2 real roots left)...

Comment: ...we see that the curve loops around 0 in what is approximately a circle of radius 1/2, and cutting back very close to the $x$-axis.  This doesn't match the behaviour we would expect by eyeballing a curve through the $f_{k,c}$.  I don't know whether to take this as evidence that there is no nice algebraic curve through the $f_{k,c}$, or just as evidence that my suggestion was a poor one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For convenience let me set $k = 2n$.

We can represent the binomial coefficient by

$$
\binom{x}{2n} = \frac{1}{(2n)!}\prod_{j=0}^{2n-1} (x-j),
$$

so to make this an even polynomial we will replace $x$ by $y+n-\tfrac{1}{2}$.  This will make the roots of the equation

$$
\binom{y+n-\tfrac{1}{2}}{2n} = c \tag{0}
$$

symmetric about the real and imaginary axes (at least when $c$ is real), effectively centering the "oval" at the origin.

It appears that the roots tend to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.  From the product representation we observe that

$$
\binom{y+n-\tfrac{1}{2}}{2n} \sim \frac{y^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$

for large $y$, so we might expect that equation $(0)$ behaves a little like

$$
\frac{y^{2n}}{(2n)!} \approx c
$$

when $n$ is large.  Multiplying both sides by $(2n)!$ and raising things to the $1/(2n)$ power the "equation" becomes, by Stirling's formula,

$$
y \approx \frac{2n}{e}.
$$

This heuristic reasoning leads us to suspect that the roots grow approximately on the order of $n$.  We'll make one more substitution to reflect this, replacing $y$ by $nz$.

In total we want to make the substitution

$$
x = nz + n - \tfrac{1}{2}
$$

into the original equation $\binom{x}{2n} = c$ and hence study the new equation

$$
\binom{nz + n - \tfrac{1}{2}}{2n} = c. \tag{1}
$$

Using the Beta function representation of the binomial coefficient we can rewrite it in terms of Gamma functions as

$$
\binom{nz + n - \tfrac{1}{2}}{2n} = \frac{\Gamma\left(nz+n+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)}{\left(nz+n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(nz-n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma(2n+1)}.
$$

We now replace the Gamma functions with their Stirling formula equivalents;

$$
\Gamma\left(nz+n+\tfrac{3}{2}\right) \sim \left(\frac{nz+n+\tfrac{3}{2}}{e}\right)^{nz+n+3/2}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{nz+n+\tfrac{3}{2}}},
$$

$$
\Gamma\left(nz-n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right) \sim \left(\frac{nz-n+\tfrac{1}{2}}{e}\right)^{nz-n+1/2}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{nz-n+\tfrac{1}{2}}},
$$

$$
\Gamma(2n+1) \sim \left(\frac{2n+1}{e}\right)^{2n+1} \sqrt{4\pi n},
$$

where the first two are valid for $\operatorname{Im} z \neq 0$ with a relative error of $O(1/n)$ as long as $z$ remains bounded away from the points $z=\pm 1$.  With a little bit of algebra we find that

$$
\binom{nz + n - \tfrac{1}{2}}{2n} \sim \frac{(2n+1)^{-2n-1}}{\sqrt{4\pi n} \left(nz+n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)} \sqrt{\frac{nz-n+\tfrac{1}{2}}{nz+n+\tfrac{3}{2}}} \frac{\left(nz+n+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)^{nz+n+3/2}}{\left(nz-n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{nz-n+1/2}}.
$$

A straightforward calculation will show that

$$
\frac{\left(nz+n+\tfrac{3}{2}\right)^{nz+n+3/2}}{\left(nz-n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{nz-n+1/2}} \sim e n^{2n+1} \frac{(z+1)^{nz+n+3/2}}{(z-1)^{nz-n+1/2}}
$$

as $n \to \infty$, so on taking absolute values and raising both sides to the $1/n$ power we obtain

$$
\left|\binom{nz + n - \tfrac{1}{2}}{2n}\right|^{1/n} = \frac{1}{4} \left|\frac{(z+1)^{z+1}}{(z-1)^{z-1}}\right|\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)\right),
$$

as $n \to \infty$, where the error term holds uniformly with respect to $z$ as long as $z$ remains bounded away from the points $z = \pm 1$.  So, after taking absolute values of both sides of $(1)$ followed by $n^\text{th}$ roots,

$$
\left|\binom{nz + n - \tfrac{1}{2}}{2n}\right|^{1/n} = |c|^{1/n},
$$

letting $n \to \infty$ yields

$$
\frac{1}{4} \left|\frac{(z+1)^{z+1}}{(z-1)^{z-1}}\right| = 1.
$$

So...

> The roots of equation $(1)$ tend to the limit curve
>   $$
> \left|\frac{(z+1)^{z+1}}{(z-1)^{z-1}}\right| = 4 \tag{2}
> $$
>   as $n \to \infty$.

Below is a plot of the roots of equation $(1)$ with $n=30$ and $c=1$ in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ along with the limit curve $(2)$ in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$.

[image]

And here is a plot with $n=100$ and $c=1$.

[image]

**Remark 1:** These calculations indicate that the rate at which the zeros approach the limit curve is $O(\log n/n)$ away from the points $z = \pm 1$.  Near these points the rate of approach should be different and a more detailed analysis is required to determine it.

**Remark 2:** The variable $c$ does not need to remain fixed; it may in fact depend on $n$.  As long as

$$
|c|^{1/n} \to 1
$$

as $n \to \infty$, the roots of equation $(1)$ will still tend to the limit curve $(2)$, though perhaps at a different rate than if $c$ were held fixed.

**Remark 3:**  With more work it is possible to obtain better approximations to the actual curve on which the roots lie.  Some rough calculations seem to indicate that

$$
\left|\frac{(z+1)^{z+1}}{(z-1)^{z-1}}\right| = 4 + \frac{\log(16e^4|c|^4n^2)}{n}
$$

is a much better one.  Here's a plot with $n = 30$ and $c=5$, showing this 'adjusted' curve as a thin blue line.

[image]

Comment: Nice approach. One thing if I can ask, that why the the roots are not on the limit curve?

Comment: Perhaps thinking about it like this will help: the curve that the roots *are* on depends on $n$, and as $n \to \infty$ the curve that they are on settles down onto the limit curve I found in the answer.  It is essentially only a first-order approximation of the curve that the roots actually lie on.  It is possible to construct better approximations to the actual curve, though it takes quite a bit more work.  We take this approach because it might not be possible to write down (in a nice way) the actual curve the roots lie on for each $n$.

Comment: Thank you @Antonio Vargas, I understand it. So it is an approximation, and it is in the case of $n \rightarrow \infty$, and the roots are of the case $n=30$. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome.  Yes, it is an approximation.  I've added a little more to the answer which may interest you.

Comment: Thank you @Antionio Vargas the details. Just a little more comment, that in case of $n=6$ and $c=1$ it is really close to an ellipse. I fitted ellipses for arbitrary $5$ points from the $6$ and I get almost the same ellipses. But as $n$ growth, we get farther from an ellipse, and this has turned out also from your analysis. Because I really was in the prison of this idea, I thought of [$n$-ellipses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse). Maybe it would be interesting to look at the foci of fitted $n$-ellipses, but as you've shown, the curve we are looking for is very special.

Comment: Simply fantastic!  Rigorous analysis backed up with excellent diagrams.